# retrieve phone number from text file using indexOf

Tags: java, swing, substring

I have a `text file` which has details like `date`,`time`,`phone number`, etc. I am trying to retrieve these details using the `java` `indexOf` concept. However, the `digits` in the `phone number` would change depending on the type of call.

How can I improve the code so I am able to retrieve every `phone number` from the file. Here's what I've been trying :

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            String getIndex="";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

     line = line.replaceAll("[\\s]+", " ");   //remove all large spaces from the file.

    /*
         the dialledNo is chosen with the help of a combo box.
         calculating the start and end index in order to print the dialled no.
        */

    int startIndex = getIndex.indexOf(dialledNo);

    int endIndex = getIndex.indexOf(" ", startIndex);

    strDialedNo= (startIndex + "," + endIndex);
```

And the code to retrieve the number is mentioned below :

```
String[] arrDialedNo = strDialedNo.split(",");

int DialedNoStart = Integer.parseInt(arrDialedNo[0]);
int DialedNoEnd = Integer.parseInt(arrDialedNo[1]);

DialedNo = line.substring(DialedNoStart, DialedNoEnd);
```

This is how my text file looks like:

```
0356  524           000   8861205063        12/03 18:59    00:08     01:20
0357  524           000   9902926868        12/03 20:01     
0373  511           000   09886863637       13/03 11:46    01:01     02:40  S
0376  504           000   9845014967        13/03 11:46    00:11     01:20
0382  508           000   04443923200       13/03 12:04    03:11     04:80  S
0411  516           000   8884103111        13/03 16:25    01:03     01:20
```

Comment: You should probably provide examples of the phone numbers you're trying to grab

Comment: Can you post results you want to achieve?

Comment: Well, firstly I traverse the file, and I have combo boxes where I select all the details like calltime, calldate etc.. and store the positions of these strings in the database. In another program, I process these dimensions, and store the details of the selected text file, in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work,

```
String[] b = line.split(" ");
    String phoneNumber = null;
    for (String x : b) {
        boolean z = false;
        if (x.length() == 10) {

            char[] c = x.toCharArray();
            for (char g : c) {
                if (Character.isDigit(g)) {
                    z = true;
                } else {
                    z = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

        } else {
            z = false;
        }
        if (z) {
            phoneNumber = x;
        }
}
```

Comment: I did try this method. But then, I have many text files and the position of the number changes. Hence, my code would not work. That's why I calculate the `start` and `end` index of the `string` that's required and print out the values.

Comment: As your line contain all digits it will be difficult to get number string.
you Can try following,

line.substring(line.indexOf("000")+3,line.indexOf("/")-2)

Comment: What if the number is stored at the first position in a different file? That is why I get the start and end index. And use the `indexOf()` function. I'm trying to make it universal and not just for one text file.

Comment: Try this

String[] b = line.split(" ");
  String phoneNumber = null;
  for (String x : b) {
   boolean z = false;
   if (x.length() == 10) {

    char[] c = x.toCharArray();
    for (char g : c) {
     if (Character.isDigit(g)) {
      z = true;
     } else {
      z = false;
     }
    }

   } else {
    z = false;
   }
   if (z) {
    phoneNumber = x;
   }
  }

Comment: Well, that certainly helps. I'll have to just change it a little bit so I can get the numbers which have less than ten digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
   /* Easiest way to to retrieve Phone number from Text file using Java */

 package TestProject.EndToEnd;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;



    public class FileReader {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

            File file = new File("//File//Path//");

            List<Object> ph = new ArrayList<Object>();

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);

            while(scan.hasNext()) {
                scan.next();
                if(scan.hasNextBigInteger()) {
                ph.add(scan.next());

                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < ph.size(); i++) {

                if(ph.get(i).toString().length()==10) {
                    System.out.println(ph.get(i));
                }
            }
        }

    }
```